# c++ inline function and pass by reference

Tags: c++, algorithm

Inline function simply copies the code to the main function, and a function that pass parameter by reference make parameter an alias for the original variable. 
My question is: for two functions with the same time complexity and other conditions, which one will process faster, make the function an inline function or pass the variable by reference?

Comment: `inline` is only a hint to the compiler

Comment: Those are two completely unrelated concepts.

Comment: The original reason behind inline was to negate the overhead of a function call, it was useful inside loops, but modern compilers already know to do that.

Comment: Premature optimization is the root of all evil.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you have a misconception about what `inline` does. It allows a function to be defined in multiple translation units and it is a *hint* to the compiler to consider inlining the function. A function might not be inlined even though it is declared `inline`, and a function not declared `inline` might, nevertheless, be inlined at link time.

Broad questions about performance are almost impossible to answer definitively. If you care about performance, I suggest benchmarking.